# Файл был изменен. Обновить его в архиве?

Tags: excel, ms-word, office, winrar

Очень часто пользователи открывают документы внутри архива, используя ПО WinRAR

И когда доходит до сохранения файла, они не замечают, что путь сохранения ведет во временную папку архиватора: **%Temp%\Rar$DIa0.105**

После чего архиватор запрашивает - "Файл был изменен. Обновить его в архиве?"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках архиватора нет функции игнорирования или выбора действия по умолчанию, и когда пользователь нажимает "Нет", файл попросту не сохраняется в архиве. Бывают случаи когда документ создается несколько часов, а то и все рабочее время. И по случайности или не внимательности пользователь делает не верный выбор.

Необходимо решение для игнорирования данного запроса от архиватора, или способ отрывать документ в архиве уже распакованным...

Comment: вы хотите лекарство от невнимательности и безграмотности пользователя что ли найти?

Comment: Именно так, иначе какой смысл от тех кто много знает но не делится с другими решением. Просто почитай по поиску гугла сколько таких ситуаций. И думаю проблема в самом архиваторе, разработчик должен был это предвидеть или прислушаться к пользователям.